# suo file not saved in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, suo

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project that recently I noticed that the .suo file is missing AND is not saved each time I exit VS.  More specifically, as I exit VS a new .suo file with 0 KB is created and then almost immediately deleted.  It seems as if VS is having trouble writing to the new .suo file and so deleted it (yes I do have write permission to the solution directory).  As a result I have no .suo file and none of my settings are saved across VS restarts.  This is very annoying.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem would drive me crazy in a similar way.

Visual Studio did NOT update the .suo file on exit which sucks pretty much.

In my case, deleting the .suo file made Visual Studio update .suo properly. (well, so far =D)

You're not lucky, though.

> I suggest you to **make any changes in your project** like outlining, breakpoint toggling, etc., and then close Visual Studio.

Give it a try.

Comment: For the record, deleting suo file worked with same problem in vs2015 (startup and break points not being saved)

Comment: @nick66 Visual Studio 2015 should take advantage of .vs folder (although my .suo is also missing under that folder)